# Is there a way to check if java object changed after submit

Tags: jsf-2

Is there a way to check if the java object changed after submitting in JSF, without storing the instance manually or quering database before persist. I am using primefaces and omnifaces framework in my application.

```
@Named("bean")
public class bean implement serialization{ 
   private Person newPerson;

   public void doSave(ActionEvent event) {
        //compare person object
        if(newPerson.equal(submittedPerson)){
            //message to user for no changes to apply
             ----
        }else{
            //do persist
             ----
        };

//getter and setter
   ---
   ---
```

Comment: Are you using JPA or Hibernate?

Comment: Its JPA implementation using eclipseLink

Comment: You can use `merge` method which will do querying, comparing and persisting updated values into database. Reference https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#EntityManager_merge.28.29

Comment: merge would be too late as there are some calculated field like lastModifiedDate etc which gets updated by @PreUpdate common MappedClass BaseEntity and change the object. What I am looking is once page is submitted for save compare with last instance without I saved manually this last instance.

Comment: Did you try `merge` method, and check if your calculated value creates any problem?

Comment: yes, for instance lastModifiedDate = new Date(); this get's update even if no change is made to object. This is one if very simple case. Anyways merge is not the option.

Comment: In general scenario, user will save something when he/she has done some changes. Do you have some real time scenario where you want to check for a single value changed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compute and compare the object's *hash code* before and after submission. That way, you will not have to store the actual object itself.

Comment: Is there any way, that I can find the hashcode of the last instance of the object to compare from doSave ActionEvent or something,  instead of storing and comparing manually.

Comment: @Raj: I do not think so. You would need to compute the hash code, store it, maybe as a session variable and then, when the user saves, you generate the new hash code and compare it with what you already have.